# Looking to add post modules deploy calling a java class in ml-gradle and roxy

Tags: java, marklogic, roxy, ml-gradle

I have a java class that I want to call on post deployment of modules for MarkLogic in both ml-gradle and roxy.  Are there any examples for either of these out there?

Answer (score 1):

For ml-gradle, is it fine to have the Java class called at the end of "mlDeploy"? If so, you can do that easily by creating a Gradle task of type JavaExec, and then having mlPostDeploy depend on it, e.g.

```
mlPostDeploy.dependsOn myCustomTask
```

If you need it to run immediately after modules are loaded and before any other ml-gradle commands are executed, you'll need to make your own command that's part of mlDeploy - see https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Writing-your-own-command for more info and feel free to post an issue in ml-gradle if you run into problems.

Comment: Instead of `mlPostDeploy.dependsOn`, one could use `mlDeploy.doLast { }`

Answer (score 0):

Roxy runs on Ruby, so you will have to do a system-call to invoke Java. We do that internally too to invoke MLCP, Corb2, XQSync, and RecordLoader:

https://github.com/marklogic-community/roxy/blob/master/deploy/lib/server_config.rb#L1399

HTH!